# Tabindex not working in IE for jquery remote validation

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-validate, tabindex

I have a site that uses http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote on the signup and login pages to check whether a username exists.

It works great in Chrome and Firefox.

However, in IE7-9, there is this problem:

If you type the username and quickly press Tab (to get to the next field), instead of focusing on the next field, the focus jumps to the browser address bar.  (Actually, sometimes it correctly focuses on the next field; it seems to depend on the speed of the remote response.)

I've tried both 1.9.0 and a fresh download of v1.10.0.

Any thoughts?

P.S. I've tested native Internet Explorer 7 on Win XP sp2 and IE9 on Win7.

Comment: If replace the guts of the "remote" function of the jquery.validate.js plugin with "return true", the problem goes away. This obviously isn't a solution but seems to be proof that the problem is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been the fix:

I had a line that focused the cursor on the username field after page load.  But since I was using Persistent Placeholder (http://jsfiddle.net/mrcoles/Kwsts/), I it did it in a roundabout way:

`$('#username').parent().children('label').click();`

When I changed it to `$('#username').focus();`, it worked.

I don't know where/why there was a conflict, but it seems to have been resolved by removing that click handler.